# Plone valuator unable to find object

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Background:
Colleague duplicated a site and then renamed it by copy and pasting in ZMI. The clients of the site then made one of the sites into a chinese version

So we have these two sites on a server everything is fine and dandy, and then a couple months ago the copied site stopped working, all urls to it bring this error http://echinaapple-cn.ucdavis.edu except instead of “copy_of_apple-check” it was a different value.

I went into zmi undo on the copied site and couldn’t find anything that had the variable in it. I then went to the original site (that is was copied from) zmi undo and found that one of the users deleted a page that had that name on it. I reverted that change and magically the copied site back up.

So now I’m in the same boat, and I see the action from 12/24/2014 that renamed something from copy_of_apple-check. The problem this time is when I try and undo plone gives me an error saying "Some data were modified by a later transaction Undo error”

Here is the only action in the ZMI undo that has copy_of_apple-check

```
/ChinaApple/folder_rename_form
Renamed ['/ChinaApple/dwarf-orchard-management/elearning/copy5_of_irrigation-of-high-density-orchards', '/ChinaApple/dwarf-orchard-management/elearning/copy_of_irrigation-of-high-density-orchards', '/ChinaApple/dwarf-orchard-management/elearning/copy4_of_irrigation-of-high-density-orchards', '/ChinaApple/dwarf-orchard-management/elearning/copy2_of_irrigation-of-high-density-orchards', '/ChinaApple/dwarf-orchard-management/elearning/copy3_of_irrigation-of-high-density-orchards', '/ChinaApple/dwarf-orchard-management/elearning/copy_of_apple-check'] by ChinaApple nmmadden
```

One of the biggest things that we can’t figure out is why the original site would still be affecting the copied site, that and how to fix the bloody thing.

We both tried to find similar errors on google but to no avail.

Things we’ve tried:

1. adding a page in the same place on the original site with the same url
2. reverting multiple lines
3. deleting the copy_of_apple-check in zmi on the chinese version (gave big error)

We can’t revert the server because we only have three days ago

If you guys have heard of this or have any ideas please let me know otherwise thanks for your time!

Original site:
http:// echinaapple.ucdavis.edu

copied unaccessible site:
http:// echinaapple-cn.ucdavis.edu

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you much. I've had similar things happen: Copy and Paste in the ZMI is NOT a real copy. You're always referencing the original objects. When I had this blow up in my face we'd tried to move objects to a separate mounted storage.

Comment: Did you clear and rebuild your catalog after making the copy? If not, these two sites are cross-referenced, and you're going to have all sorts of odd errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I *can* help.

You can always truncate the ZODB at the appropriate time on 12/24: which of course means you lose any later changes to the working site (obviously, there can't have been any changes to the other site).

You may be able to establish what's changed on the working site since 12/24, export it, and reimport after truncating.

Then you need to *completely* separate the two sites, separate ZODBs and preferably separate ZOPE servers, to ensure this can't happen again. I'd export all the Chinese content and import to a new Plone site.

Here's the script I use: it's reliant on having a buildout configuration that uses **collective.recipe.backup**  to perform regular backups, but you should be able to plug in any ZODB file as input (it might be easiest, though to add **collective.recipe.backup** to the buildout, rerun buildout, run a backup on your existing ZODB, and then run this script.

**No matter what, SAVE A COPY OF YOUR CURRENT ZODB first!**

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.6 zopepy

# Standalone usage:
# cd to the directory containing this script, then
#  HTTP_REFERER=anything ./restoreDB.py yyyy-mm-dd [hh:mm:ss]
#
# The HTTP_REFERER environment variable needs to be set to any non-null value
# to make the script think it's being called in a CGI setting
# The arguments are a date/time stamp in Local time.

import cgi
import cgitb
import datetime
import time
from dateutil import tz
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
import logging
import os
import re
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
import sys
import ConfigParser
from ZODB.FileStorage import FileIterator
from ZODB.TimeStamp import TimeStamp as ZODBTimeStamp
cgitb.enable()
zeo = ''
loglevel = logging.INFO
logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/recover.log',level=loglevel,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

def restartZeo():
    subprocess.check_call([zeo, 'start chone-zeo'])

def execute(cmd, stdin='', shell=False):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr= subprocess.STDOUT, shell=shell)
    output, error = proc.communicate(input=stdin)
    logging.info(cmd)
    logging.info(output)
    if proc.returncode > 0:
        restartZeo()
        print "\n"
        raise Exception("Aborted")
    return output

def start():
    print "Content-type: text/html"

    global zeo
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    logging.info(form)
    restore_date = date_parse(form.getfirst('restore-to-time', ''))
    restore_date = restore_date.replace(second=59,tzinfo=tz.tzlocal()).astimezone(tz.tzoffset(None, 0))
    logging.info('restore_date: %s' % restore_date)

    referer = os.environ.get('HTTP_REFERER','')
    if not referer:
        print "\n"
        raise Exception('HTTP_REFERER (%s) does not appear to be part of the Plone site' % referer)

    # read the buildout's .installed.cfg file
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open('../.installed.cfg'))
    # get the path to the backup command
    try:
        paths = re.split(r'\s+',config.get('backup','__buildout_installed__'))
        backup= [x for x in paths if x.endswith('/backup')][0]
    except:
        print "\n"
        raise Exception("Can't find the path to the backup command")
    bin = os.path.dirname(backup)
    site= bin.split(os.sep)[-2].split('-')[-1]

    stopped = False
    # shutdown the ZEO before we start the recovery
    # we try to do it from the parent directory's "supervisorctl", otherwise directly 
    # from the local zeoserver command
    for cmd in ['/../../bin/supervisorctl','/zeoserver']:
        zeo = bin+cmd
        try:
            subprocess.check_call([zeo, 'stop %s-zeo' % site])
            stopped = True
            break
        except:
            pass

    if not stopped:
        print "\n"
        raise Exception("Could not stop the ZEO server.")

    # get the path to the Data.fs
    db = config.get('backup','datafs')

    # determine the first backup FOLLOWING the time given 
    repozo_date = restore_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
    logging.info('repozo_date: '+repozo_date)
    backup_path = config.get('backup','location')
    logging.info('backup_path: '+backup_path)
    # get the list of backups (most recent first)
    files = [x for x in sorted(os.listdir(backup_path),reverse=True) 
             if x.endswith('sz') and x > repozo_date]

    # take a backup before we start, but only if:
    # - there is no backup containing the repozo_date or,
    # - the latest backup is older than the current db
    # this prevents dropping our last full backup off the cycle when we
    # immediately decide to restore the original file after a previous restore
    current_ts=time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(db)) # the modification timestamp of the current database
    if len(files) == 0 or files[0] < time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S',current_ts):
        execute([backup])
    # if we found an older backup we need restored:
    if len(files) > 0:
        # do a restore to the end of the first backup after the time we really want
        repozo_date = files[-1].split('.')[0]
        logging.info('repozo_date: '+repozo_date)

        output = execute([bin+'/restore', repozo_date], stdin='yes\n\n\n')
        for line in output.splitlines():
            if 'restoring database file' in line:
                db = line.split(' to ')[1]
                break

    # find the next transaction after our timestamp
    ts  = list(restore_date.timetuple())[:6]
    tid = repr(ZODBTimeStamp(*ts))
    it  = FileIterator(db, tid)
    f   = open(db, 'r+b')
    # truncate the database at that transaction
    logging.info('truncating db at %d' % it._pos)
    f.seek(it._pos)
    f.truncate()
    f.close()

    # restart the zeo
    execute([zeo, 'restart %(site)s-zeo %(site)s-plone' % locals()])
    # redirect to the Restore page
    print "Location: %s\n" % referer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from optparse import OptionParser
    parser = OptionParser()
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    os.environ['QUERY_STRING'] = "restore-to-time=%s" % ' '.join(args)
    start()
```

Comment: I was afraid you'd want it :-) I haven't Ploned for a few years now and have to dig it out...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by going back and adding the content onto the old site in the same location.

I didn't have to use your script Auspex!